# realizar insert com o codigo usuario logado,em uma tabela no banco de dados

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin

Olá estou desenvolvendo um formulário, assim que o usuário submeter o formulário eu gostaria que no banco de dados na tabela ficha, fosse inserido o código do usuário logado, juntamente com as outras informações preenchidas no formulário, nessa tabela, para que fique gravado no banco o código do usuário que inserir aquelas informações, segue meus códigos abaixo.

pagina index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>.::COMMEQ UDIA::.</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

<form action="validacao.php" method="post">
  <div class="login-wrap">
 <div class="login-html">
  <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab">Login</label>
  <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab"></label>
  <div class="login-form">
   <div class="sign-in-htm">
    <div class="group">
     <label for="login" class="label">login</label>
     <input id="login" name="login" type="text" class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="group">
     <label for="senha" class="label">Senha</label>
     <input id="senha" name="senha" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
    </div>
    
    <div class="group">
     <input type="submit" class="button" value="Acessar">
    </div>
    <div class="hr"></div>
    
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 </form> 
  

</body>

</html>
```

Pagina validacao.php

```html
<?php
    
  // Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
  if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['login']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
      header("Location: index.html"); exit;
  }
  
   // Tenta se conectar ao servidor MySQL
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
  // Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
  mysqli_select_db($con,'db_uberlandia') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
    
  $login = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['login']);
  $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['senha']);
    
   // Validação do usuário/senha digitados
  $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `CodUsuario`, `NomeUsuario`, `nivel` FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`NomeUsuario` = '".$login."') AND (`senha` = '".$senha."') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1");
  
  if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 1) {
      // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
      echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
  } else {
      // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
      $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  }
  
   // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
      if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    
      // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
      $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['CodUsuario'];
      $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['NomeUsuario'];
      $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];
    
      // Redireciona o visitante
      header("Location: restrito.php"); exit;
    
 ?>
```

Pagina do formulario que quero salvar no banco

fichaCadastralMusica.html

```html
<?php
 
  // A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    
  // Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
  if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID'])) {
      // Destrói a sessão por segurança
      session_destroy();
      // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
      header("Location: index.php"); exit;
  }
    
  ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Ficha Cadastral Música - Formoid php contact form</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fichacadastralmusica_files/formoid1/formoid-solid-blue.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fichacadastralmusica_files/formoid1/jquery.min.js"></script>



 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modificadonovo.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>

 function mascara(t, mask){
 var i = t.value.length;
 var saida = mask.substring(1,0);
 var texto = mask.substring(i)
 if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
 t.value += texto.substring(0,1);
 }
 }
 </script>

 
 
</head>
<body class="blurBg-false" style="background-color:#fff">



<!-- Start Formoid form-->

<div id="menu"></br>
  <a href="menuMusica.php"><button type='button' class='btn btn-md btn-info'>Voltar</button></a>
   
  
 </div>
<form class="formoid-solid-blue" action="salvarFichaCadastralMusica.php" style="background-color:#e2e2e2;font-size:16px;font-family:'Roboto',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#080c10;max-width:480px;min-width:150px" method="POST"><div class="title"><h2>Ficha Cadastral Música</h2></div>
 <div class="element-input"><label class="title"><span class="required">*</span></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="ieqbairro" required="required" placeholder="I.E.Q Bairro:"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 <div class="element-input"><label class="title"><span class="required">*</span></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="pastor"  required="required" placeholder="Pastor:"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 <div class="element-input"><label class="title"><span class="required">*</span></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="lider" id="lider" required="required" placeholder="Líder:"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Células Ativas:</label>  <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="celulasativas" value="Sim" /><span>Sim</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
  <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="celulasativas" value="Não" /><span>Não</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="number" min="0" max="100" style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="participantescelulas" id="participantescelulas" placeholder="Participantes Celulas Quantidade" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="number" min="0" max="100" style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="quantidadereunioes" id="quantidadereunioes" placeholder="Quantidade Reuniões" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="number" min="0" max="100" style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="quantidaensamensal" id="quantidaensamensal" placeholder="Quantidade Ensaios Mensais" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 <div class="element-multiple"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><div class="large"><select data-no-selected="SELECIONE...." name="diaensaio" id="diaensaio" multiple="multiple" >

  <option value="Segunda">SEGUNDA</option>
  <option value="Terça">TERÇA</option>
  <option value="Quarta">QUARTA</option>
  <option value="Quinta">QUINTA</option>
  <option value="Sexta">SEXTA</option>
  <option value="Sabado">SABADO</option>
  <option value="Domingo">DOMINGO</option>
  </select><span class="icon-place">
  </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="element-input"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="text" name="horaensaio" id="horaensaio" onkeypress="mascara(this,'--:--')" maxlength="5" placeholder="Hora do Ensaio"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="totalmembrosdepartamento" id="totalmembrosdepartamento" placeholder="Total de Membros do departamento:" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="vocal" id="vocal" placeholder="Vocal:(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title">Mulheres</h3></div>
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="mulhercontralto" id="mulhercontralto" placeholder="Contralto(qtas)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="mezzosoprano" id="mezzosoprano" placeholder="Mezzo-soprano(qtas)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="soprano" id="soprano" placeholder="Soprano(qtas)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title">Homens</h3></div>
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="homensbaixo" id="homensbaixo" placeholder="Baixo(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="baritono" id="baritono" placeholder="Barítono(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="tenor" id="tenor" placeholder="Tenor(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="guitarrista" id="guitarrista" placeholder="Guitarrista:(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="bateristas" id="bateristas" placeholder="Bateristas:(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="tecladistas" id="tecladistas" placeholder="Tecladista:(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="violao" id="violao" placeholder="Violão(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100"name="baixistas" id="baixistas" placeholder="Baixistas(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="meialua" id="meialua" placeholder="Meia Lua(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="medium" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="cajon" id="cajon" placeholder="Cajon(qtos)" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-input"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="text" name="outros" id="outros" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Outros:"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
 <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Ministério de carreira:</label>  <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="ministeriocarreira" value="Sim" /><span>Sim</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
  <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="ministeriocarreira" value="Não" /><span>Não</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>
 <div class="element-textarea"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><textarea class="medium" style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="nomeministeriocarreira" id="nomeministeriocarreira" cols="20" rows="5" placeholder="Nome dos ministérios de carreira"></textarea><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
 
<div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Salvar"/></div></form>



<!-- Stop Formoid form-->



</body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="fichacadastralmusica_files/formoid1/formoid-solid-blue.js"></script>
</html>
```

Pagina que salva as informações no banco de dados

salvarFichaCadastralMusica.php

```html
<?php

 include ("validacao.php");
 
 
$_SESSION['CodUsuario'];
$ieqbairro = $_POST['ieqbairro'];
$pastor = $_POST['pastor'];
$lider = $_POST['lider'];
$celulaAtivas = $_POST['celulasativas'];
$participantes = $_POST['participantescelulas'];
$quantidadereunioes = $_POST['quantidadereunioes'];
$quantidaensamensal = $_POST['quantidaensamensal'];
$diaensaio = $_POST['diaensaio'];
$horaensaio = $_POST['horaensaio'];
$totalmembrosdepartamento = $_POST['totalmembrosdepartamento'];
$vocal = $_POST['vocal'];
$mulhercontralto = $_POST['mulhercontralto'];
$mezzosoprano = $_POST['mezzosoprano'];
$soprano = $_POST['soprano'];
$homensbaixo = $_POST['homensbaixo'];
$baritono = $_POST['baritono'];
$tenor = $_POST['tenor'];
$guitarra = $_POST['guitarrista'];
$baterista = $_POST['bateristas'];
$tecladista = $_POST['tecladistas'];
$violao = $_POST['violao'];
$baixo = $_POST['baixistas'];
$meialua = $_POST['meialua'];
$cajon = $_POST['cajon'];
$outros = $_POST['outros'];
$ministeriodecarreira = $_POST['ministeriocarreira'];
$descrinomemstcarreira = $_POST['nomeministeriocarreira'];
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$db = mysqli_select_db($connect,'db_uberlandia');
mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf8');
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ficha_Cadastral_Musica (CodUsuario,ieqbairro, pastor, lider, celulaAtivas, participantescelulas, quantidadereunioes, quantidaensamensal,diaensaio, horaensaio, totalmenbrosminis, vocalquant, mulhercontralto, mulhermezzosoprano, mulhersoprano, homensbaixo, homensbaritono, homenstenor, guitarraqtd, bateristaqtd, tecladistaqtd, violaoqtd, baixoqtd, meialuaqtd, cajonqtd, outros, ministeriodecarreira, descrinomemstcarreira) VALUES ('$_SESSION['CodUsuario']','$ieqbairro', '$pastor', '$lider', '$celulaAtivas', '$participantes', '$quantidadereunioes', '$quantidaensamensal', '$diaensaio', '$horaensaio', '$totalmembrosdepartamento','$vocal', '$mulhercontralto', '$mezzosoprano','$soprano', '$homensbaixo', '$baritono', '$tenor', '$guitarra', '$baterista', '$tecladista', '$violao', '$baixo', '$meialua', '$cajon', '$outros', '$ministeriodecarreira', '$descrinomemstcarreira')") or die('Erro ao inserir ao banco de dados'); 
 
if($query){
      /* echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'><div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong></div>;window.location.href='menuMusica.php'</script>";*/
   
   echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    }
    

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Bom ai quando eu submeto o formulario, é apresentado esse erro na tela, veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está nesta parte: `... VALUES ('$_SESSION['CodUsuario']', ...`. 
Como a string está sendo criada a partir de aspas duplas (") o PHP utiliza um recurso adicional na leitura da string. Esse recurso é responsável pela leitura das variáveis, caracteres especiais ("\n" para pular linha) e valores de array/objetos para que o conteúdo destas sejam interpolados ao texto.

Exemplo de string literal

```
$name = 'Victor';
$text = 'Hi, $name!'; // Note o uso de aspas simples
echo $text; // Saída: Hi, $name!
```

Exemplo de string "complexa"

```
$name = 'Victor';
$text = "Hi, $name!"; // Note o uso de aspas duplas
echo $text; // Saída: Hi, Victor!
```

---

Outro ponto importante é que uma string é delimitada pelas aspas, ou seja, para este caso `"... VALUES ('$_SESSION['CodUsuario']', ..."` temos dois textos delimitados pelas aspas simples: `'$_SESSION['` e `']'`. Então, quando o interpretador de strings identificar a possível variável `$_SESSION[`, retornará o erro que você está recebendo. Para resolver esse problema, segue algumas sugestões.

Atribuir o valor da sessão em uma variável:

```
$codUsuario = $_SESSION['CodUsuario'];
$query = "... VALUES ('$codUsuario', ...";
```

Concatenar usando o ponto (.):

```
$query = "... VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['CodUsuario'] . "', ...";
```

Ou usando chaves:

```
$query = "... VALUES ('{$_SESSION['CodUsuario']}', ...";
```

---

> O uso de chaves é primordial para arrays e objetos podendo também ser utilizado com variáveis em casos específicos.

```
$name = 'Victor';
echo "{$name}'s Family"; // Victor's Family
```

Comment: Victor muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, a parte da session, me parece que deu certo, mais agora quando vou submeter o formulario da o seguinte erro.


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ieqbairro' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\commeq\salvarFichaCadastralMusica.php on line 7

Comment: Você esqueceu de adicionar o ponto-e-vírgula após a atribuição `$codUsuario = $_SESSION['UsuarioID']`.

Comment: Victor funcionou, muito obrigado mesmo viu, parabéns pelo seu conhecimento... :)

Comment: Dê nada @RAVlog, fico feliz em ter te ajudado. Não esquece de marcar como melhor resposta \o/

Comment: estou com outro problema agora, queria depois que inserisse no banco os dados que apresentace um alert bonito na tela, estou tentando fazer dessa forma.
if($query){
 
    echo "<div class="panel panel-success">
              <div class="panel-heading">Dados Salvo com Sucesso!</div>
             
       </div>";
 
 
    }
mais não da certo aparece o erro

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'panel' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\commeq\salvarFichaCadastralMusica.php on line 41

Comment: Sempre fique alerta com as aspas e ponto-e-vírgula. No seu  caso o ideal é utilizar um IDE que mostre os erros que você comente ao decorrer da codificação.

if($query) { echo '<div class="panel panel-success"><div class="panel-heading">Dados Salvo com Sucesso!</div></div>'; }

Comment: veja a imagem que coloquei abaixo, tipo isso que estou querendo fazer.